# Display a thank you message instead of a page redirect after submitting a Webform in a block?

Tags: 7, webforms

I am using the [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) module, and I've created a block containing a webform. When I submit the form, my browser goes to the main url for the webform.

How can I display a thank you message instead?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it, from the webform configuration page: Use *Redirection location* or *Confirmation message*.

> [image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Use [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) in your custom module (better create a new custom module). Get the form id for the webform A using inspect element or firebug. Once done, you alter the submit handler for the webform.

The #redirect is what makes you to redirect to webform url, you might need to unset or change that. Use [Drupal_set_message()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_message/7) in your custom submit handler to print the thank you message.

Answer (score 0):

Reference of the link : [Creating a hook_form_alter for webform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5105608/drupal-form-alter-in-webform-forms)

ou just need the id of the node and then use the id like in hook_form__alter()

the FORMID generated is webform_client_form_

where NODEID is the id of the node

so if you have a module named mymodule and a node with id 44 which has a webform

```
function mymodule_form_webform_client_form_44_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
$form['#redirect'] = 'your path';
}
```

Comment: can you please tell me what I put in the place of mymodule ? and there I this code ?in side template.php right ?

Comment: your custom module name that is hook_name you should place above in your custom_module you may have created

Comment: I used webform module and crated block for webform ,its no working

Comment: https://drupal.org/node/542202 ->this is the link for creating a .info file and then create a .module file and inside that write the above code.Create a directory  with the module name and place .info and .module file inside it .Enable the module and then you can work on the code and change the path using #redirect

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the below step to redirect webform submission.

- Create a node using "Basic Page" content type or you can create any custom page or any panel page.
- Edit your Webform page. When you edit your webform node, you will find "view", "edit", "webform" links in your top of page.
- Click on "Webform" link in top of page and it will display the webform configuration for the node.
- Click on "Form settings" in webform configuration.
- In the "Redirection location" section, check radios button "Custom URL" and add the url of your page in textbox.

Kindly see that if you will create node content, then your url will be "node/[nid]" or if you create any custom page or panel page, then your url will be different.